# Spring RestTemplate content type mismatch

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest

I am trying to consume one of the REST web service from Terremark enterprise cloud. Here is what I have done:
1) Take the xsd and generate jaxb artifacts
2) Send Rest call and let Restclient populate the Organizations class.

```
ResponseEntity exchange = template.exchange("https://services.enterprisecloud.terremark.com/cloudapi/ecloud/organizations/", 
                    HttpMethod.GET, 
                    new HttpEntity(operation.getInput(), operation.getHeader()), 
                    Organizations.class, 
                    urlVariables);
```

The error I see is

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [com.dto.Organizations] and content type [application/vnd.tmrk.cloud.organization;type=collection]
```

In the above error, com.dto.Organizations is generated java class by JAXB. Any generic Spring pointers to resolve this issue would also be helpful.

P.S.
In spring dispatcher, I have following:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
           <bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" 
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter"
            p:marshaller-ref="jaxb2Marshaller" p:unmarshaller-ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are going to need to set the content-type handled by your `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`:

```
...
<bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" 
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter"
        p:marshaller-ref="jaxb2Marshaller" p:unmarshaller-ref="jaxb2Marshaller" 
        p:supportedMediaTypes="application/vnd.tmrk.cloud.organization"/>
...
```

...something along those lines. The default supported media type for `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` is simply `application/*+xml`.